# store an image created using MATLAB fill function into a variable

Tags: image, matlab, variables

How do i store an image created using MATLAB fill() function into a variable so that i can use it further in my code?

My fill() function:

```
axis ( [ 0, 1, 0, 1 ] )
x1 = [ 0.0, 0.5, 0.5 ];
y1 = [ 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 ];
fill ( x1, y1, 'r' )
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Using saveas and then imread?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have the Image Processing Toolbox (in which case using [`poly2mask`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html) to directly generate the image would probably be a better option), [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) and [`frame2im`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/frame2im.html) are probably the nicest way.

Quoting the example code from the docs:

```
f = getframe;              %Capture screen shot
[im,map] = frame2im(f);    %Return associated image data 
if isempty(map)            %Truecolor system
  rgb = im;
else                       %Indexed system
  rgb = ind2rgb(im,map);   %Convert image data
end
```